# Bad operand types for binary operator '>'

Tags: operands

I get an error on this line of my code.

```
if (age < 17) {
        System.out.println("You are a adult");
```

The error is Bad operand types for binary operator '>'

This is my full code

```
package transition.work;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 *
 * @author New
 */
public class TransitionWork {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Hello, what is your name?");

        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    System.out.println("Type name:");
    String name = reader.readLine();
    System.out.println("Hello "+name+", How old are you?");
    String age;
        age = reader.readLine();

    if (age < 17) {
        System.out.println("You are a adult");
        }  

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that you are comparing `age` (a string variable) to `17` (an integer literal). Try converting `age` to an integer using `Integer.parseInt()`.